# Control System Block Diagram Notation

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

How does one annotate initial conditions on a control system block diagram.  Specifically, if $Y(z)$ corresponds to the system output, $X(z)$ to the system input, and $G(z)$ to the plant:

$$Y(z)=G(z)X(z)$$

If $y(0)\neq0$ is there a way to include the information $y(0)=y_0$ in the block diagram?

Comment: Recall that the transfer function itself assumes that all initial conditions are zero.

Answer (score 0):

Generally no. Linear control theory frequently (though often tacitly), assumes the initial condition is zero. Since for a stable system the IC decays at the rate of the fastest timeconstant this simplifying assumption makes sense, since any action by the control system will have little effect on the IC transient.

Answer (score 0):

The Transfer function is a mathematical model that relates the output variable to the input variable. It is a property of a system that is independent of the input. The applicability of the concept of the transfer function is limited to linear, time-invariant systems.A system is said to be linear if it follows the principle of superposition and homogeneity. Homogeneity principle implies that *zero input gives zero output*. If we assume that the initial conditions are not zero, then it is a non- linear system.  If you are looking for an LTI system, it is not possible to include *y*(0) it in the block diagram.